# How to get the (latitude/longitude/altitude) position using GPS only (offline)?

Tags: javascript, cordova, gps, geolocation, hybrid-mobile-app

Is there anyway to get  (latitude/longitude/altitude) position using GPS only (offline) ?

We're looking forward to build hybrid application which has to get GPS coordinates (offline)

I don't need to use google maps - just GPS info !!

I used [this](https://market.ionic.io/starters/offline-gps) (with ionic) and a simple app with [this plugin](https://github.com/apache/cordova-plugin-geolocation)

both required the internet connection to get the GPS info

> Note : the application will work indoor not outdoor (inside building)

Comment: research `navigator.geolocation`

Comment: Yeah, sure.  GPS (GPS is positioning; navigation is not GPS, not to be confused...) is not a Google Maps feature, it's a HTML5 feature that's built into your webbrowser. http://www.w3schools.com/html/html5_geolocation.asp

Comment: `Note : the application will work indoor not outdoor (inside building)` You will almost certainly **not** get a GPS signal indoors ([see here](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Indoor_positioning_system#Relation_to_GPS)). Indoor navigation requires a different solution, such as Bluetooth beacons.